# base64decode returning blank

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to decode this base 64 encoded url string and it keeps returning blank why is that?

```
return strtr(base64_encode($url), '+/=', '-_,');

return base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/='));
```

encoded url is this aHR0cDovL3Rlc3QuZ3J5cGhvbnRlYS5jb20vbWFnZW50by9zdG9yZS5odG1s

Comment: Just cause your strtr in the decode is useless.
Try just : 
return base64_decode($url);

Answer (score 2):

Just cause your strtr in the decode is useless.
Try just :

```
return base64_decode($url);
```

your url was :

> http://test.gryphontea.com/magento/store.html

That should do the job.

```
base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/='));
```

With strstr you try to go to substring "-_,", and in your encoded url there is no such part. Then you try to base64_decode it, as strstr "fail" it return "".
then you've got :

```
base64_decode("");
```

Comment: I tried several time using without strtr() it still returns blank.. Is there any requirement to use this base64_decode?

Comment: @zaw You must be doing something else. Try calling `var_dump` on the results of the `base64_decode` call.

Comment: is this the server related thing?? even this only show "test"....
<?php 
echo base64_decode('aHR0cDovL3Rlc3QuZ3J5cGhvbnRlYS5jb20vbWFnZW50by9zdG9yZS5odG1s') . ' test';
?>

Comment: Probably due to your encoding.
mb_convert_encoding( $string, "UTF-8", "BASE64" )
try that.

And a echo mb_detect_encoding($url); to check encoding of the string.

Comment: shit i just found out that echo out phpinfo() base64_decode was listed in the disable functions for some reason :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe convert your $url first to a $var, do your conversions, and then return the string, but I'm not convinced your strtr conversion is correct.